# Confusion about Fourier transform of some simple functions

Tags: fourier-transform

According to the book "Linear Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers" by Tyn Myint-U. and Lokenath Debnath, on page 446

> Many simple functions, such as a constant function, $sin ωx$, and $x^n H
>  (x)$, do not have Fourier transforms even though they occur frequently in applications

But from some tables of Fourier trasnfrom

$$\mathscr{F}_x(1)=\delta(k)$$

and

$$\mathscr{F}_x[\sin(x)](\omega)=i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\delta(\omega-1)-\delta(\omega+1))$$

Can someone please explain?

Comment: what is $H(x)$?

Comment: That's the difference between having a Fourier transform as a function, and having one as a tempered distribution.

Comment: @FrankMoses I think it is the Step function.

Comment: @FrankMoses [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)

Comment: $\delta(\omega)$ is a distribution, but not a function.  In certain applications, a Fourier transform in terms of $\delta$s doesn't "count", since it's not actually a function.